# JekyllRB: how to create an online book (force permalink to be like chapter/1)

Tags: ruby, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

Jekyll by default uses specified variables to generate permalink. But in my case I need permalink to use page specific variable like `chapter` to generate url something like `/chapters/:chapter` instead of using date and other stuff

Comment: Using collections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use any front matter variable to create your permalinks, only [the Jekyll defined keys for the type of page](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/).

To get the URLs you're after, you could use collections, as Wickramaranga said. In your _config.yml, you define your chapters collection:

```
collections:
  chapters:
    output: true
    permalink: /chapters/:title/
```

Then create your chapters, e.g. `/_chapters/1.md`, `/_chapters/2.md`.

That'd create http://localhost:4000/chapters/1/ and http://localhost:4000/chapters/2/